# multi-select dropdown and form field shows as array?

Tags: arrays, forms, coldfusion, coldfusion-2016

I am using ColdFusion 2016. I have a form with a multi-select drop down. The `name` attribute of the field is called `jobRoleId`.  When I submit this form the field name is available in the form scope as `jobRoleId[]`.  How do I get the value of this field?  The name comes across like an array but I can't seem to just dump out the value due to the brackets.

I've tried dumping out the value, but I get an error.  I feel like I have done this in the past and the form field name didn't contain the brackets [] after the field name when using a multi select menu:

```
<select id="jobRoleId" name="jobRoleId" multiple="multiple">...</select>
```

Is there a way to somehow have the form field name just come across as `jobRoleId`?

```
writedump(jobRoleId[]); 
abort;
```

Comment: To access fields with invalid characters, use structure notation:  `form["jobRoldId[]"]`.  *When I submit this form the field name is ... "jobRoleId[]"* I think something else is responsible for the name change, not CF. I just tested it with CF2018 and even when `this.sameFormFieldsAsArray = true;`, it still submitted the field name as "jobRoleId".

Answer (score 2):

When I execute your code I get a comma separated list for the values of jobRoleId.  Are you using any CF frameworks?

My output:

[image]

I also suggest looking at the client side JavaScript to confirm there's nothing changing the submitted name. You can use the Chrome/Firefox/IE debugger to watch your submissions and confirm what is being submitted

Comment: I also suggest looking at the client side JavaScript to confirm there's nothing changing the submitted name.  You can use the Chrome/Firefox/IE debugger to watch your submissions and confirm what is being submitted.

Comment: I am using the Coldbox framework @JasonHolden.  I also am using jquery's $.ajax method and form.serialize() to send the data in so maybe is causing the values to come through this way.

Answer (score 1):

Multi select lists, in CF, should return a list of values, as far as I remember...